# protobuf java runtime installation

Tags: windows, protocol-buffers, protoc

I'm trying to build the Java runtime library for Protocol Buffers on Windows. I have downloaded and installed the binary distribution of protoc: protoc-3.3.0-win32 .  I have downloaded the protobuf-master from https://github.com/google/protobuf. and tried to build Java runtime library using Maven. I ran `mvn test` from D:\protobuf-master\java

These errors occured when I ran `mvn test`.

```
`[INFO] Results:
 [INFO]
 [ERROR] Errors:
 [ERROR]   MapTest.testPut:1248 ╗ IllegalArgument
 [ERROR]   MapTest.testPutForUnknownEnumValues:494 ╗ IllegalArgument
 [INFO]
 [ERROR] Tests run: 908, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0
 [INFO]
 [INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------
 ----
 [INFO] Reactor Summary:
 [INFO]
 [INFO] Protocol Buffers [Parent] .......................... SUCCESS [  
 0.000 s]
 [INFO] Protocol Buffers [Core] ............................ FAILURE [01:23 
 min]
 [INFO] Protocol Buffers [Util] ............................ SKIPPED
 [INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------
 ----
 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
 [INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------
 ----
 [INFO] Total time: 01:24 min
 [INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-27T20:40:21+02:00
 [INFO] Final Memory: 32M/720M
 [INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------
 ----
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-
 plugin:2.20:test (default-test) on project protobuf-java: There are test 
 failures.
 [ERROR]
 [ERROR] Please refer to D:\protobuf-master\java\core\target\surefire-
 reports for the individual test results.
 [ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, 
 [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
 [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
 [ERROR]
 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e 
 switch.
 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 [ERROR]
 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, 
 please read the following articles:
 [ERROR] [Help 1] 
 http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
 [ERROR]
 [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the 
 command
 [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :protobuf-java`
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior was changed after 3.3.0 so either checkout v3.3.0 or compile newer version of protoc.
[Commit](https://github.com/google/protobuf/commit/bf483dfb99a5b7c57ee0a222bd041275cda9cf98)